# Bootstrap Modal Works On Mobile Device Only

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, desktop, bootstrap-modal

Hello,

I created a bootstrap 3 modal and it works on my mobile device but on my desktop when you click the button it does not open the modal.

I've tried resizing the modal box even adjusting it's zindex but those did not fix the problem.

Does anyone know what the issue is i'm having?

```
<div class="container-fluid formbox ">
  <div id="cageModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Cage The Great</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VqghSmwdnpg" frameborder="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">See More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid formbox ">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <h3>Get Familiar with the artists below.</h3>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cageModal">Cage The Great</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Non-working code on jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PatrickFunom/2jxxpe34/#&togetherjs=9hEip09byq)

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors, you might also want to change **http** to **https** on your bootstrapjs link (also, bootstrap contains normalize css by default just as an FYI)

Comment: I did, and there weren't any errors. Thanks for the normalize bit. I made the adjustments to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. But your bootstrap references (CDN) are not.

replace your references to Bootstrap with the latest. Or better yet, use Bootstrap locally and never touch it!

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is your broken [**jfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2jxxpe34/2/), now working

Comment: Wow, it's really that finicky? Cool, i made the adjustments to my project folder on cloud9 and the modal still didn't pop up. I'll paste a link to the page.  https://wintersoulstice-ptlergo.c9users.io/artistspage.php

Comment: jquery over bootstrap.js ;) always